# Does Amazon DocumentDB support BI Connector?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I want to know whether Amazon DocumentDB is compatible with the BI-Connector or not?

Good new that Amazon DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility) is now available in the Asia Pacific (Singapore) region. And this region is target for me. 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-documentdb-available-in-asia-pacific-region/

Please give me advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS DocumentDB is compatible with the BI-Connector.

DocumentDB engine is same as MongoDB.

But, DocumentDB can't get public IP and public access. So, we can't connect it in external.

> See :
>
> Here's [a document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html) about `Connecting to an Amazon DocumentDB Cluster from Outside an Amazon VPC`

If you connect DocumentDB using external application, should to use `SSH tunneling`.

First, make EC2 instance in same VPC.

Second, install `openssh-server` to that instance.

third, config your PC with `SSH tunneling`. and Run your application

> See :
>
> Here's [a document](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) about `SSH tunneling` example.

Comment: Greats greats. We will follow your advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GNOKOHEAT: any way to use `mongosqld` to connect DocumentDB in the same VPC, EC2?

Comment: @WorkWe: you can connect `document DB` is only 2 way `same VPC` or `SSH tunneling` whatever your application.